# What is the name of this effect?

Tags: angular, loading

What is the name of this effect?

Hello everyone, I'm making an application in angular 5.
I have seen some pages that show forms of the component that is being loaded and while the whole page fully loads that effect it will be displayed.
It is like a loader but very interesting because it works for small components.

Youtube has that effect when you upload a video attached an image.

[image]

Could you tell me the correct name of this functionality or framework that works with angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called `skeleton screen`. These are nothing but gifs or normal html with animation effect which act as placeholder while actual data loads. Skeleton screens helps in improved perceived performance of your application.

Here is a demo :

```js
// As soon as content is added to the skeleton screen container, the `:empty` pseudo-class won't match anymore and the background will be automatically removed.
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.demo').innerHTML = '<h1>Injected content.</h1>';
})
```

```css
/* 
Animated skeleton screen using CSS.

Create shapes using gradients that simulate solids.

Use `:empty` pseduo-class to show skeleton screen background only while container has no content (ex: for the "loading" state). When content is added to the container element, the pseudo-class selector won't match anymore and the skeleton screen will be removed automatically; no need to toggle a separate class on the container.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Animating one layer of the background which is a tilted linear gradient with white in the middle to achieve shine effect.
*/
 .demo:empty {
    margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px; /* change height to see repeat-y behavior */
    
  background-image:
   radial-gradient( circle 50px at 50px 50px, lightgray 99%, transparent 0 ),
   linear-gradient( 100deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80% ),
   linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 ),
   linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 ),
   linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 ),
   linear-gradient( lightgray 20px, transparent 0 );

  background-repeat: repeat-y;

  background-size:
   100px 200px, /* circle */
   50px 200px, /* highlight */
   150px 200px,
   350px 200px,
   300px 200px,
   250px 200px;

  background-position:
   0 0, /* circle */
   0 0, /* highlight */
   120px 0,
   120px 40px,
   120px 80px,
   120px 120px;

  animation: shine 1s infinite;
 }

 @keyframes shine {
  to {
   background-position:
    0 0,
    100% 0, /* move highlight to right */
    120px 0,
    120px 40px,
    120px 80px,
    120px 120px;
  }
 }
```

```html
<button>Add content</button>
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Comment: glad to help you